# Search excel spreadsheet or Microsoft access within sharepoint

Tags: search, excel, access, batch

I have a spreadsheet with a list of batch jobs. I was wondering if it's possible to create some type of search into a sharepoint to search this spreadsheet. We are using sharepoint and if I could have a page on sharepoint with a search bar, and when i paste a batch job in there it will read off the spreadsheet and give me the results only for that specific job.

Is that possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your satisfaction with the results will depend on the version of SharePoint you are using. It would probably be easier in 2013 than 2010, though I would start with Excel Services instead. You could use the REST service to search the columns you desire for the results. This is such a specific case I think your best choice is ExcelREST.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cumgranosalis/archive/2009/11/02/excel-services-rest-apis-the-basics.aspx